# jsfiddle work error

Tags: css, menu, jsfiddle

I made my menu at jsfiddle and here's my work.

but I got different result on my page.

is jsfiddle working?
do I need to modify some code?

```
<div id="menu_main">

  <ul>    
    <li class="mainop"><a href="#">Category</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href='../index.php?category=Blogging'>Blogging</a></li>
        <li><a href='../index.php?category=General'>General</a></li>
        <li><a href='../index.php?category=Arts and Entertainment'>Arts and Entertainment</a></li>

        <li><a href='../index.php?category=Womens Interests'>Womens Interests</a></li>
        <li><a href='../index.php?category=Writing and Speaking'>Writing and Speaking</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>  

</div>
```

my script

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".mainop").hover(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.find("ul").slideDown("fast");
        $this.children('a:first-child').addClass('active');
    }, function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.find("ul").slideUp("fast");
        $this.children('a:first-child').removeClass('active');
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to JSFiddle, the output HTML of your code looks like this:

```
<div id="menu_main">
    <ul>
        <li class="mainop"><a href="#">Main option</a>
            <ul style="display: block; "></ul>
        </li>
        <li class="mainop"><a href="#">Main option</a></li>
        <li class="mainop"><a href="#">Main option</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

All the list elements are gone.

I can see that you're referencing the [columnizer jQuery plugin](http://welcome.totheinter.net/columnizer-jquery-plugin/), but you haven't included it in your JSFiddle page. That could be the reason you're not getting the same results. If you remove the call to `columnize`, the list elements reappear, but it doesn't look pretty.

Comment: how can I included that plugin? I already downloaded it to your link

Comment: Why do you need to perfectly duplicate your site menu to JSFiddle? My answer was only intended to explain why you're not getting the expected results. In any case, to include the plugin, just add a script tag anywhere on the page with the src property pointing to the plugin hosted on the internet somewhere.